# Aligning List of Figures Page

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Sorry if this quetion have been unanswered previously, but I am unable to follow the possible solutions in simmilar previous questions asked in the forum. I am very new to LaTex. Currently, I am writing my dissertion paper which use a certain template. Using the template, I am getting the following List of Figures page:

[image: Current Style]

While I want something like this:

[image: Expected Style]

I am currently using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,notitlepage,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft} % it serves to make lists of the most beautiful figures and tables

\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure } % to add "Figures" in the list of figures

% List of Figures
\phantomsection
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\cleardoublepage
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue in case list entry with long sentences.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380835/134144 could be useful.

Comment: Thanks, it worked @leandriis

Answer (score 1):

Please read again the `tocloft` documentation.

```
% lofprob.tex SE 561254
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

%\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }  % put Figure before number
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5em} % need more space for Figure + number

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{figure}
\centering
 A FIGURE
\caption{Regular caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
ANOTHER FIGURE
\caption{A caption that will take more than one line in the List of Figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Use `\cftfigpresnum` to put something before the number and increase `\cftfignumwidth` to allow for the increased space required for the modified number.